# In Texshop for Mac OS, I am unable to create a personal shell script that automatically parses in the tex file name

Tags: macros, pdftex

I have a personal executable shell script in /usr/local/bin that reads:

```
#!/bin/sh
pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 -output-dir=outfolder "mytexfile.tex"
```

However, each time I run typeset (CMD-T) in Texshop with this script in preferences, it prints:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**
```

Then, when I hit Enter, I get:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**
Please type the name of your input file.
**
```

which then compiles if the input file is specified. Is there a way to do this automatically? thanks.

Comment: the  `**` prompt is the expected behaviour if no file is specified. Check you don't have another command of the same name in your path that doesn't have the "mytexfile.tex" at the end.

Comment: Thank you, somehow there was another pdflatex command outside of the tex `/Library/TeXShop/bin` version! Would not have guessed this, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The `**` prompt is the expected behaviour if no file is specified. Check you don't have another command of the same name in your path that doesn't have the `"mytexfile.tex"` at the end